# android - Selected Item Color on Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml

How can I change the color of the selected item in the navigation drawer.

Here is a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCwrq.jpg

The highlights on the selected item is white, how can I change it to something different, like red for example.

I tried using a list selector but I can't seem to pinpoint the correct state.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/red"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `android:state_selected`?

Alternatively in your adapter you can change background of selected item, something like this:

```
public void setSelectedPosition(int position){
            mSelectedPosition = position;
        }



@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        //....

        if(position == mSelectedPosition) {
            //apply different color
        } else {

            //revert to normal
        }  

}
```